# Load file into AWS server using scp

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

I'm trying to copy a file from a local mac directory to a Linux aws server using scp and i keep getting the error: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic when I run the following command?

scp -i /path/to/kp/keypair.pem /Documents/to/upload/tourmaline.zip ec2-x-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/

(the amazonaws part we copied the public dns from the instance)

when we run ssh /path/to/kp/keypair.pem ec2-x-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com it works, but not with scp, and suggestions?

I'm expecting to get the file loaded onto the linux aws servier, we tried messing with different paths and flags

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `scp` command is missing the user, you should prepend `ec2-user@` to `ec2-x-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`:

```
scp -i /path/to/kp/keypair.pem /Documents/to/upload/tourmaline.zip \
ec2-user@ec2-x-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/
```